# Electron setInterval implementation difference between chrome and node

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, electron

I'm quite new to using electron and I'm having a problem that seems to be to do with the `setInterval()` function. I'm importing a library named `exiftool-vendored` which in turn depends on a library named `batch-cluster`.

Batch cluster is crashing when I import it because it expects a return value from `setInterval()` of class `Timeout` which is what the node implementation returns. Instead it returns an integer which is what chrome returns. See the docs here for the two different implementations:

- https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

So I have a few questions in regard to this

1. Is the problem what I think it is?
2. How would I solve it? I'm thinking of forking the `batch-cluster` library, is there a better solution that doesn't require this?
3. Does this happen often in Electron? Are there functions defined in both Node and Chrome which have the same name but behave differently?

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question!

Josh

Comment: I don't think you can use exiftool within the renderer process at all. exiftool-vendored needs access to the filesystem. Access to the filesystem you have mostly within your main process. So do you'r stuff within the the main process and use ipcRenderer/ipcMain or remote to trigger your actions from the renderer process. In this case exiftool-vendored is executed from within nodejs and ever thing is fine.

Comment: which process you imported module?

Comment: @slowjack2k Ah yes that makes much more sense. Thanks for your help

Comment: @slowjack2k This is incorrect, the renderer can access the filesystem, and you should *not* be running expensive code in the main process

Comment: @paul Betts that's why I said mostly. And yes you should not do expencive work within the main process but at the renderer process neither.  Take a look at Cameron nokes deep dive into electrons main and renderer processes and electron-remote module.

Comment: fam, I _wrote_ the electron-remote module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a great idea to do long running tasks in the Electron main process, it can cause lots of issues.

I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/mceachen/batch-cluster.js/pull/2) to `batch-cluster` which should fix the issues when it makes it into `exiftool-vendored`.

Comment: Author of exiftool-vendored and batch-cluster here--thanks for the PR!

Comment: v4.18.1 has your fix. Thanks.